# Paritial match in two excel sheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

In excel I have two sheets.

Sheet 1 is like this:

```
Name  Type  
----  ----
A1    f  
A2    C  
B1    I  
B2    I   
B3    C  
C1    5  
C2    r  
Yr1   5  
Yr2   5
```

Sheet 2 is like this:

```
Name  Location  
----  -------
A     AL  
B     CA  
C     NY
```

I want to find the rows in sheet 1 with partial match with sheet 2 with reference to the variable Name. Like, I want to find all rows with name containing "A" or "B" or "C", which are the values in sheet2.

And the final sheet should be like this:

```
Name Type location  
---- ---- --------
A1    f   AL  
A2    C   AL  
B1    I   CA  
B2    I   CA   
B3    C   CA  
C1    5   NY  
C2    r   NY
```

How shall I write a formula to reach this?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post a sample "finished" table, that shows what you want to output?  I understand that you want to find a row number, from sheet 1, that matches your sheet 2 ...then what? What's the variable name?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I will post a output sample.

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula in cell C1 of Sheet1 and then copy it down:

```
=VLOOKUP(LEFT(A1,1),Sheet2!A:B,2,FALSE)
```